# Extracting values from a single file

Tags: sed, terminal, extract

I have a file with multiple lines; but a specific line contains tons of information, with several repeated expressions. I'm trying to extract some specific values. I first tried some commands with sed, for instance, but with no success. So, I was wondering if you could give me some insights.

So, here you have one fraction of the unique line of the given document I mentioned:

```
    [...]6[&length_range={0.19
    [... a lot of more information here in between ...]
     0.01},habitat.set.prob={0.01,0.03,0.56,0.01,0.01,0.34,0.01,0.01,0.01},DLOOP.rate_median=0.04131395026396427,length=
    [...]
     10[&length_range={0.19
    [... a lot of more information here in between ...]
     0.01},habitat.set.prob={0.21,0.33,0.56,0.01,0.01,0.33,0.01,0.01,0.61},DLOOP.rate_median=0.04131395026396427,length=
    [...]
```

My aim here is first to extract all the values that is between the brackets, after "habitat.set.prob={".  and put them in a single line in a text file.

Also, it would be important to extract the numbers that appears just before the expression "[&length_range=]", which in this case are "6" and "10". They are the label of the set of numbers after "prob={"

So the set of numbers I want to extract always appears between "habitat.set.prob={" and "},DLOOP.rate_median", while the other number (the label) is always rigth before "[&length_range="; but what is before the label is not the same expression; actually it is a random number.

The goal then is end up with a file with the following characteristcs:

```
    6 0.21,0.33,0.56,0.01,0.01,0.33,0.01,0.01,0.61
    10 0.21,0.33,0.56,0.01,0.01,0.33,0.01,0.01,0.61
    and so on …
```

What do you think? Is this possible?

I started with this very basic command at least to try to extract the set of numbers, but it didn't work

```
    sed -n "/habitat.set.prob={/,/},DLOOP.rate_median=/ p"
```

|  Well... I got some improvement.
I was able to get the values at least:

```
     awk '{gsub("habitat.set.prob={","\n");printf"%s",$0}' filename | awk -F'},' '{print $1"}"}' | grep -iv "TREE" > stats.txt
```

|

Many thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Luiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
sed -rn '/.*[0-9]+\[&length_range=\{/,/habitat.set.prob=\{/{s/.*\b([0-9]+)\[&length_range.*/\1/p; s/.*habitat.set.prob=\{([^D]+)\},DLOOP.rate.*/\1/p}' habitat 
6
0.01,0.03,0.56,0.01,0.01,0.34,0.01,0.01,0.01
10
0.21,0.33,0.56,0.01,0.01,0.33,0.01,0.01,0.61
```

The first part '/.a./,/.b./' searches from pattern a to b, distributed over multiple lines. The -n told sed to do non-printing as default.

In `'/.a./,/.b./{s/.c./.d./p; s/.e./.f./p}'`

there are two substitution commands with p=print in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you really digged a little, so not providing the complete answer, but let's hope this would help you:

for the first part: getting the no(which you call as label) you didn't mention if there is any specific pattern, so try this (data is the file which contains the actual input) - you need to work on how to get the number and tweak the RE a bit

`sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*length_range.*/\1/p' data`

For the other part which gives the numericals between habitat and DLOOP:

`sed -n 's/.*habitat.set.prob=\(.*\),DLOOP.*/\1/pg' data | tr '{' ' ' | tr '}' ' '`

Now, try to take this as a starter and work on your output to get your desired result!

To explain a bit:

In the first section - I am trying to capture the numericals between anything(.*) and (.*)length_range [you can escape the character [ and & by using \ in front of them]

In the second section: I am capturing pattern in between habitat.set.prob and DLOOP and then doin a tr to remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string p = "1:2:3:4"; //input your string
    int arr[4] = {}; //create a new empty integer array to put the integers  in it
    for(int i=0, j=0; i <p.length(); i++){//loop on the string to extract integers
        if( p[i] == ':'){continue;}//if the value = ':' skip it and continue
        arr[j]=(int)p[i]-48;j++;//put the integer in the array we created

    }
    cout << "String={"<<arr[0]<<" "<<arr[1]<<" "<<arr[2]<<" "<<arr[3]<<"}";//print the array

    return 0;
}
```